# jQuery dropdown query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

Initially my code was as follows, `#ddlcompetition` is an html `<select>` element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#ddlcompetition').val('@comp');
    $("#ddlcompetition").change(function () { onSelectChange('@baseurl'); });

});
```

Where '@comp' has value of the corresponding query string parameter. But since it is in lower case, I want to iterate all `<options>` of the `<select>` element so that I can set the matching option as the selected option.

Comment: yeah it's a lot of words that i recognize, but they don't really make sense next to each other. maybe rephrase with more examples?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ddlcompetition option').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase() == comp.toLowerCase()){
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected'); //Select the matching option
    }
});
```

Comment: @hetalgala: Do mark as correct answer whichever idea helped you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var comp='@comp';
$('#ddlcompetition option').val(function(i,val){
        return val.toLowerCase()==comp; 
}).prop('selected',true).change(function () {onSelectChange('@baseurl'); });
```

Comment: tried this.. sets new value but it is then not firing on select change event

Comment: this was only code to get value set on page load... don't know what change is supposed to do

Comment: tried but same output...on change is doing as below                  function onSelectChange(href) {

        var comp = $("#ddlcompetition option:selected").text().LTrim();
        $(window.location).attr('href', href + "?" + "comp=" + comp.toLowerCase());

        
    }

Comment: please next time post all code in original post that pertains to your situation....try this  ...onSelectChange(href) {
    var comp = $("#ddlcompetition option:selected").text().toLowerCase();
    $(window.location).attr('href', href + "?" + "comp=" + comp.toLowerCase());
}